# Postgres GROUPBY on data coming from JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, group-by

Given the table `orders` containing two columns:

```
| order_id | json |
| ---------| ---- |
| order_1 | {...} |
| order_2 | {...} |
| order_3 | {...} |
```

I want to end up with a table having one row for each order and the associated total number of items bought, which can be computed using the json.

**Json structure** (example for order_1):

```
{
"id": order_1, 
"line_items": 
    [
    {"id": product_1, "quantity": 1}, 
    {"id": product_2, "quantity": 2}
    ]
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
| id | quantity |
| -- | -------- |
| order_1 | 3 |
| order_2 | 1 |
| order_3 | 2 |
```

This is the code written so far:

```
SELECT 
order_id,
json_array_elements_text(raw_data::json#>'{line_items}')::json->>'quantity' as quantity_lines
FROM orders
```

which outputs the following table:

```
| order_id | quantity_lines |
| -------- | -------------- |
| order_1 | 1 |
| order_1 | 2 |
| order_2 | 1 |
| order_3 | 1 |
| order_3 | 1 |
```

I'm missing the last step of aggregating on the order_id. I've tried a traditional `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
order_id,
sum((json_array_elements_text(raw_data::json#>'{line_items}')::json->>'quantity')::int) as quantity_lines
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_id
```

but it yelds the following error:

```
postgresql error: aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost close. Let's wrap it with CTE.

```
with a as (SELECT
order_id,
json_array_elements_text(raw_data::json#>'{line_items}')::json->>'quantity' as quantity_lines
FROM orders)
select a.orderid, sum(quantity_lines) from a group by 1 order by 2;
```